# Parsing json with Iphone

Tags: iphone, json, parsing

I am working with JSON parsing for the first time on Iphone. I need to parse the following json string:

```
{
EmpMaster : 
[
    {"empId" : 1,"firstName" : "Yogesh","lastName":"Chaudhari","isSupervisor" : "1","supervisorId":"1"},
    {"empId" : 2,"firstName" : "Sahil","lastName":"Khurana","isSupervisor" : "1","supervisorId":"1"},
    {"empId" : 3,"firstName" : "Anutag","lastName":"Chaudhari","isSupervisor" : "1","supervisorId":"1"},
    {"empId" : 4,"firstName" : "Sameer","lastName":"Vaidya","isSupervisor" : "1","supervisorId":"1"}
]
}
```

Please provide me with some sample code or link with the help of which i can parse the json string and separate the empId, firstName, lastName, isSupervisor and supervisorId.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add **[JSON Framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/)** . It will simply parse your JSON String and return you NSDictionary with all the keys.

**MODIFIED**

Download Zip file from **[this link](https://github.com/downloads/stig/json-framework/SBJson_3.0.1.zip)**

```
1. Open Folder and rename Classes folder to "JSON". 
2. Copy JSON Folder and include in your project.
3. Import header file like below in controller where you want to parse JSON String.

#import "SBJSON.h"
#import "NSString+SBJSON.h"

4. Now, Parse your response string in to NSDictionary like below.

    NSMutableDictionary *dictResponse = [strResponse JSONValue];
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi Deeps.Can you please give me some sample code to parse above json string?i am quite new with using json on iphone

Comment: @Shraddha Harne Have a look at the link sent and the tutorials suggested by other answers.  Stackoverflow is not a copy and paste source code repository.

Comment: @Shraddha I have modified my answer. Hope that help.

Comment: Hi. .i am not looking for any copy and paste source code repoitory. Only the thing is i am new so i thought if anyone has done it earlier and can help me.Anyways i will get it working.I have very less time so i was seeking help

Comment: Thanks Deeps.I really appreciate your quick help.I will try it out

Comment: @Shraddha My Pleasure. Please mark it answer if it works so other developer can use this answer.

Answer (score -1):

One of the most popular framework is [touchJSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON#). Easy to add, easy to use.